# How can I use .reduce() to add all of the values within a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm fairly new to using .reduce() and am wondering what the best to find the sum of all of the numbers inside myArr would be.

```
const myArr = [ [ 10, 0 ], [ 10, 0 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
```

Comment: what is your exptected result?

Comment: the expected result should be  32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the array and then sum

```js
const myArr = [
  [10, 0],
  [10, 0],
  [2, 4],
  [2, 4]
]

console.log(
  myArr.flat().reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
)
```

Comment: Could also use `[].concat.apply([], myArr)` instead of `Array#flat` for es5 support

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is probably what Tibebes. M already proposed, but here are two more:

```
myArr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr[0] + curr[1], 0)
```

and

```
myArr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.reduce((innerAcc, innerCurr) => innerAcc + innerCurr, 0), 0)
```